# How to disallow zero in textbox using char.IsDigit

Tags: c#

I have the below code wherein it works for only numbers and backspace but I want to also have that no zeros are allowed, but it is not working

```
private void TxtNumber4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) || (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) || (int)e.KeyChar == 0)
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(LblNum2, "");
                LblNum2.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                errorProvider1.SetError(LblNum2, "Allow Only Numeric Values !");
                LblNum2.Text = "Allow Only Numeric Values !";
            }
        }
```

Comment: `e.KeyChar` is of type `char`, and casting that to `int` results in the ASCII value 48. You can use `atoi()` or subtract the char `0` to get the integer value.

Comment: Much simpler: Just compare it directly to `'0'` instead...

Comment: Hm... No zeros allowed vs. `"Allow only numeric values"` – and what about e.g. `1012`? Do you really want to disallow or have you overlooked such cases? `0` itself is numeric, too – if you really want disallow then you might adjust your text (e.g. `"Only positive numbers allowed"`), still the very first issue remains open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the other end, i.e. what we *allow*: `'1'..'9'` (note they are `char`s, say `'1'` is *not* `int` `1`) and all the control chars:

```
private void TxtNumber4_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
  // If e.KeyChar is a control character
  //   or it some char from '1'..'9' we allow it
  if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar >= '1' && e.KeyChar <= '9') {
    LblNum2.Text = "";
  }
  else {
    e.Handled = true;
    LblNum2.Text = "Allow Only Numeric Values !";
  }

  // Let's not repeat ourselves
  errorProvider1.SetError(LblNum2, LblNum2.Text);
}
```